# Is it possible to run transpiled JS code (from Typescript) in place of TS files with React Native?

Tags: javascript, ios, typescript, react-native

Recently we have been working on converting our React Native application from using Javascript to Typescript. I have our app working with Typescript just fine. However, I have been asked to determine if we can use the compiled Typescript files (.js) in the place of the converted Typescript files (.ts). I have looked all over for ways to do this and found nothing concrete, is this possible?

We are running our app through an Xcode project. I've tried hard replacing the transpiled JS files, and as I suspected that didn't work.

Here is my tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
      "outDir": "./dist",
      "allowJs": true,
      "target": "es5",
      "lib": ["es2018", "dom"],
      "jsx": "react-native"
  },
  "include": [
      "./app/**/*",
      "./index.ts"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Wait what? You cannot run TS, you always run JS (transpiled from TS files if you use TS). So what you want to do is what you already do. BTW, what is a `converted typescript file` ?

Comment: By converted typescript file, I mean a file that use to have the .js/.jsx extension that was converted to .ts/.tsx. My Xcode project which was built to run the old .js files is now running the same files but only now they are .ts. So is it possible to use the new compiled .js instead of the current .ts files I am using? I understand it can be run in node js, but I am trying to get it working with Xcode

Comment: If you only rename a .js/.jsx file to .ts/.tsx, the only thing it will do is slowing the transpilation by analysing .ts files that don't contain any typescript. But I don't think this is the real problem here. 
First, remember this: nothing runs TS directly. TS basically only typechecking above JS, at the end, you always run JS, so do not try to replace JS files by TS files in the output of your project. Second, you don't want to mess with the XCode project. React Native produce the proper output, don't mess with it, if it runs, then it is cool, don't bother with file extensions.